# Grabbing "layered" HTML text that's linked through beautifulsoup w/ python

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, beautifulsoup

Hopefully I named that properly. So, I've been trying to grab info from a website for some time now and can't seem to format the info properly, I'm unsure if there's some concept I'm not understanding or if it's some basic syntax issues. 
The HTML itself is like this:

```html
<div style="color: #555555; line-height: 16px">
  <a style="color:#0269BD;text-decoration:underline" href="javascript:SelectMapTab()">street address<br> State, zip</a><br>
  <div style="padding-top: 4px;" id="dvFacilityHourParent">
  </div>

  <div style="padding-top: 4px;">
    Phone: <b>
                                            ###-###-####</b>

    <br>
  </div>

  <div>
    Email:
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OpenOutlook('weird long string of #'s','secure1')">

    </a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-top: 4px; display: ">
  </div>
```

I'm trying to get the state and zip now, which is the first part, and save that to later be exported to an excel sheet. I haven't even bothered attempting that since I can't manage to pull the data itself. I don't know if this is part of the reason, but I had to grab the links to the site that has this information from google, so I basically have code for links from a google search in a list. I use those links in a for loop, and traverse trying to parse those websites text as html. This is what I have currently:

```
for i in range(0,MAX):  #Goes through the max sites, appends list with sites
    newList.append(links[i][links[i].find(char1) : links[i].find(char2)]) #delimited to grab just the site info
    site = requests.get(newList[i].format(query)) 
    info_soup = soup(site.text, "html.parser")   #grab HTML from specific sites
    for num in info_soup.find_all('div',{'style': 'padding-top: 4px;'}):
```

so after this, I initially had it so that I would try and save that info to a variable, but if I do that, I get a huge string of HTML "in" the variable and I don't know the best way to go through all that string just for the zip/state. The idea of having to sort of "substring/delimit" your way through to the text seems a bit counter intuitive and it seems like I'm understanding something wrong here. Is this the case?

Edit: Thanks to mahesh I understand now how to grab the general text, but a new issue has arisen around the fact that emails seem to be linked to an image and outlook number? Very odd, is there any way to grab this?

Comment: Extracting the data from the HTML you pasted above isn't itself a problem. Simple `find` code will do the trick. However, as you've guessed, pasting the links from Google search is probably causing some issue. Can you show us a sample of links you copied? And what is `char1` and `char2`? Bottom line, are you sure by the time the request is sent, you're getting the appropriate page? Try saving that locally and opening it in browser just to make sure you've fetched the correct page.

Comment: As for the data extracting part, take a look at the BeautifulSoup documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/. That should get you started. For instance, `soup.find(text=re.compile('Phone')).nextSibling.text.strip()` will get the the phone number (###-###-####).

Comment: Hm, thank you, the code for the phone numbers helped me understand quite a bit. But that also brings up more quests. Apparently the email list is an image with an outlook link to the email? Is there any way to capture the email from the source code? That really has me puzzled.

Comment: @Mahesh Char1 and char2 were specific characters in the HTML that are in between the site links I needed. It was rather complicated, I had to use cached versions of the site as the person who runs it seems to have errors on the main site.